# Visual Studio SR Report joining data from multiple Data sets?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Wondering if anyone can help me, I am currently learning, SRSS Reports and have been tasked with a Pay & Display vehicle registration report, for staff and student carparks, to show if they are registered for P&D. I have the report laid out as a 3 table column; Name, Vehicle Number and Vehicle Registration. I have from the below code set out in my datasets the Vehicle Number and Vehicle Registrations pulling through, with a parameter to filter out if is staff or student pay and display. However I am having difficulty with pulling the Staff and Student names into one name column as they are through two different datasets. Can anyone be of help at all please? TIA

Comment: assuming that being Staff or Student is exclusive something like select staff.name + student.name as PNDNAME from  a join b....  empty values will not display so it will look like a column from one table

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the code, but in general, to join between two different datasets you use LOOKUP.

LINK
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-lookup-function?view=sql-server-2017

The basic format:

```
=LOOKUP
(
Fields!key column from the dataset assigned to the table.Value,
Fields!key column from the dataset you are matching to.Value,
Fields!column you want to bring back.Value,
"the name of the other dataset"
)
```

Warning: Performance can be pretty bad if they're big datasets. You might be better off creating a new dataset that already does this work in the database.